# Codeigniter - Why Update_batch only one line is changed

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table example

```
ID | answer1 | answer2   | question

1  | abc   | ghi    | 

2  | def   | klm    |
```

I Wanna update column question by select ID
This my code to get ID form table example

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM example');
    $data=array();
    foreach($query->result() AS $value){
        $data[] = $value->id;

    } 
$implode = implode(',',$data);
//get from post
$question= $this->input->post('question');
foreach($question AS $q){

        $data[]=array(
        'id' => $implode,
        'question' => $q
        );

        }
        $this->db->update_batch('example',$data,'id');
//I use multiple add filed
<button class="add_field_button2">Add More Fields</button>
<input type="text" name="question[]" value="<?= $rowk->question;?>">
```

When add 2 question for update the table onlu one row is changed

My data array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1,2 [question] => question1 ? ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1,2 [question] => question1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 107,108 [question] => question2 ) )
```

Comment: whats in your data array ??

Comment: I have updated, I entered the data array, please see my post

Answer (score 0):

If you use the update_batch then your array format must be like this

```
Array(
    [0]=>Array(
            [id]=>1,
            [question] => question1 ?
        ),
    [1]=>Array(
        [id]=>2,
        [question] => question1 ?
    ),
    [2]=>Array(
        [id]=>107,
        [question] => question2
    )
)
```

I think your array format is not correct

Comment: the problem solved,, you'r correct my array format is wrong

Comment: Great! it solved your issue, if my comment helped you then you can upvote my answer and accept my answer

Answer (score -1):

Hello there you can check my answer [Codeigniter - Update Multiple Row With Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044207/codeigniter-update-multiple-row-with-select2/53045215#53045215) I think this will help you something, if it does hit a like button :-D . thanks
just change this

```
foreach($question AS $q){

        $tempdata=array(
        'id' => $implode, // this must be a single value i think because by default update_batch third parm is work like "=" not "IN"  
        'question' => $q
        );
  array_push($data, $tempdata);
 }
        $this->db->update_batch('example',$data,'id');
```

Comment: hey . can you little mention here what 's not working . because its the same thing that above dev. has mentioned. your array format was not right so its good to use array_push to manage your multi array if your are using update_batch in CI,.. you can check the reference link as well. both are same problem thanks.